# How do internal smtp servers send mail to internal mail servers on the network?

Tags: windows-server-2003, email-server

We have upgraded our internal corporate email server and the IP address has changed internal to our network. A second email server is used for sending bulk jobs for a mailing list service that we offer.

Since the switch of the internal corporate server IP we have been seeing problems when the bulk email server is trying to send email to our own domain. The log shows that it is still trying to hit the old corporate server instead of the new one. I have looked through all settings for the bulk email software and see nothing set there to send to internal mail servers, and I do not recall doing anything special to get this working when setup a couple years ago.

Is there a setting in Win2003 or on the network that enables the mapping of MX record external IPs to internal IPs so mail gets routed correctly?

Comment: What mail server(s) are you using?

Comment: Zrinity XMS Server

Comment: So, you can't spam yourself!  Am I the only one who thinks that ironic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Exchange 2003 (I'm assuming you are as you indicated Windows Server 2003), you could just setup an SMTP Connector on the bulk mailing server with `yourdomain.com cost 1` (make sure your default SMTP connector has `* cost 5` or it'll never match yourdomain.com on the new send connector) and add your corporate mail server as the smarthost.  This will ensure that anyrecipient@yourdomain.com gets routed through the corporate mail server; anyrecipient@*.tld will get routed out normally.

EDIT

Has your firewall changed?  MX records correct?  From your bulk mail server, try this from the command prompt:

'nslookup' hit ENTER then `set type=mx` hit ENTER again, the type in yourdomain.com and first make sure that the MX records resolve correctly and secondly, try to telnet to that MX record like so:

`telnet <mx.record.tld> 25` if you get back a `220 Microsoft Exchange xxx` (you can type `quit` to exit) then you can connect to your mail server via NAT reflection (going out and back in again) so the issue must be elsewhere in the bulk mail software.

If only your new mail server has changed, then it's likely your new Exchange Server is not allowing connections and/or you're trying to relay from somerecipient@yourdomain.com, which will be denied by default.  You can open up the Default Virtual SMTP Server and under Connections and Relay settings add  to the "allowed" list for both relay and connections (or you can use SMTP authentication if the bulk mailer supports it).

If neither of these are the issue, and since you seem to be limited to configuration choices on your bulk mail server software, you could create a Zone in Active Directory (assuming you're using Active Directory for DNS internally) for yourdomain.com and then add an MX record which resolves to your Exchange Server's internal IP address so that when your bulk mail server looks up the MX record for yourdomain.com, it gets the internal MX record (which in turn needs to resolve to your internal IP address for your mail server).  The only problem with this method (split DNS) is that you need to make sure your internal DNS zone is identical to your external/Internet DNS zone for yourdomain.com, otherwise, if anyone tries to hit up www.yourdomain.com internally or whatever you won't have any/the correct records to do that.

Comment: I'm using a different server (in my reply above) and there does appear to be a similar option that accepts an IP for "Redirecting mail to a local delivery SMTP server". However it isn't currently setup so I don't understand how this ever worked. I'll give it a shot

Comment: Nevermind, that option is for incoming mail.

Comment: edited question accordingly.

Comment: It turned out to be an internal DNS setting that allowed this to work previously. I found and updated the MX record. This was my initial thought as to what might be going on but a consultant who helped us with the new server suggested it would be in the bulk server settings. I think there was just some miscommunication between the two of us about what was going on, probably due to my my lack of experience with AD/DNS. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might need to setup an internal DNS server for your bulk mail server to point to.

On the internal DNS server you will assign your MX records for your domain to the new internal IP address. Then for all other domains the DNS server should be set to forward to a "regular" DNS server that will be able to resolve the addresses for mail recipiants outisde of your domain.

This allows you to control where your internal MX records for your domain point to, while allowing lookups to outside domains to be processed as normal.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried pointing the dns name and/or ip of the old mail server to the new one?  It's slightly hack, but may help diagnose if nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

First, I check the configuration for the mail server. Since you apparently don't have internal DNS overriding the external mail address, there is likely some exception built into the mail server configuration for your domain.  I don't know specifically how to do it for your server.

Second, check the HOSTS file on the bulk mail server.  That may be how the IP is overridden to the internal address.  You may also want to clear the ARP cache on the bulk mail server.

Third, check the firewall .. there may be some screwy NAT rule for traffic from the bulk mail server.

Another alternative (which I like better and would likely do anyway) is to put the bulk server in a DMZ, at which point you should be able to setup the same NAT on the DMZ as exists on the outside world.